# Ionic back button not showing in nested navbar view

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple use case but the back button doesn't seem to show.

From the ionic-starter-sidemenu, I want to show the back button when any of the navbar links are clicked except for the 'Home' link.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0QvDB9snhlnsIfMHidbS

So even though the link 'Browse' is a nested view of 'Playlists' , it is not showing the back button.

```
.state('app.browse', {
  url: "/playlists/browse",
  views: {
    menuContent: {
      templateUrl: "browse.html"
    }
  }
});
```

But, this single playlist view does show the back button:

```
.state('app.single', {
  url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
  views: {
    menuContent: {
      templateUrl: "playlist.html",
      controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

## Edit:

So I found out the back button shows if the 'Browse' link is clicked from the 'Playlists' view:

[image]

But it doesn't show when the same 'Browse' view is loaded from the navbar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to show the back button if a link is clicked from the navigation view:

Instead of using href or ui-sref on the link, call $state.go() from controller

```
<ion-list> 
    <ion-item menu-close ng-click="goTo('app.browse')">
        Browse
    </ion-item> 
</ion-list>

$scope.goTo = function(name){
        console.log("going to state: " + name);
        $state.go(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a similar issue with my application, I added this:

Immediately below the opening `<ion-view>` in browse.html.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" ng-click="goBack()">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i>
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

In your controller.

```
$scope.goBack = function() {
    $state.go('app.single');
}
```

*Make sure `$scope` is injected.

Comment if you have any questions.